# Using string @insertion sort in 1D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

So basically i've been working for over 2 hours on this program trying to figure out how to sort names out using compareTo method with insertion sort yet none of my research or ideas worked. I am a beginner at java so it's a bit hard for me.
how to use this method to sort out the names i can't get around to figuring it out.

```
package insertion.sort;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InsertionSort {
public static void swap (int x[] , int y , int z){
int temp;
    if (x[y]<x[y-1]){
temp=x[y];
x[y]=x[y-1];
x[y-1]=temp;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    String a[]=new String[10];
int i;    
for (int ii=1 ; ii<=5 ; ii++){
 System.out.println("Enter the "+ii+" name");
a[ii]=in.nextLine();
}



for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
for (int j=i;j>0;j--){
//a[j].compareTo(a[j-1]);
if (a[j].compareTo((a[j-1])))

    { 

 String temp=a[i];
a[i]=a[j];
a[j]=temp;}
}

}

for (int k=0;k<6;k++){
System.out.println(k);
}   



}
}   
____________________________________________
```

THANK YOU SOLVED!!!!!!!!
 Answer:

```
package insertion.sort;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InsertionSort {
public static void swap (int x[] , int y , int z){
int temp;
    if (x[y]<x[y-1]){
temp=x[y];
x[y]=x[y-1];
x[y-1]=temp;
}
}

 public static void main(String[] args) { 
 Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   String a[]=new String[5];
int i;   
for (int ii=0 ; ii<5 ; ii++){
System.out.println("Enter the "+ii+" name");
a[ii]=in.nextLine();

}

for (i=1 ; i<5 ; i++){
for (int j=i;j>0;j--){
if (a[j].compareTo(a[j-1])<0)
    { 
 String temp=a[j];
a[j]=a[j-1];
a[j-1]=temp;}}}
for (int k=0;k<5;k++){
System.out.println(a[k]);
}   
}
}
```

Comment: What is and where is your question?

Comment: [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) returns an integer `<0`, `0` or `>0`, not a boolean. You'll want to swap when it's `>0`.

Comment: What i want is how to sort the names using the method above , i may have loads of errors but i know it works.                                                                            if (a[j].compareTo((a[j-1]>0))) that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), you will see that the `compareTo` method returns a number:

> the value 0 if the argument string is equal to this string; a value
>   less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string
>   argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is
>   lexicographically greater than the string argument.

In this line

```
if (a[j].compareTo((a[j-1])))
```

you try to evaluate an `int` as a `boolean`, which is surely not what you want to achieve. If you want the program to enter into the `if` if `a[j]` is lexigographically smaller than `a[j-1]`, then you want

```
if (a[j].compareTo((a[j-1])) < 0)
```

if you want it to enter into the `if` if `a[j]` is lexicographically bigger than `a[j-1]`, then you want

```
if (a[j].compareTo((a[j-1])) > 0)
```

Your program uses a double cycle to sort the results, the outer cycle iterates the `String`s, the second cycle iterates the `String`s located at smaller or equal indexes as the current outer index and swaps neighbor elements if needed. This is not insertion sort, as you already inserted the elements before. You need to do the logic found in the inner cycle while you are reading the elements.

You are beginner, but not only in Java. You need to write structured code and yo read after the methods you are using.